how to give values to the input that is in nested artboard in rive from flutter
flutter: Instance of 'RuntimeArtboard' (-1) -> Ani1
flutter: Instance of 'RuntimeNestedArtboard' (2) -> Ani2
void _onRiveInit(Artboard artboard) {
    var controller = StateMachineController.fromArtboard(
      artboard,
      'SM1',
      onStateChange: _onStateChange,
    );

    artboard.addController(controller!);
    _var1 = controller.findInput<double>('var1');  // its in parent board
    _var2 = controller.findInput<double>('var2');  // its in nested board

    setState(() {
      _stateMachineController = controller;
    });
  }

when I try to access the _var2.values its showing as null.
_var1 values are fine.
second artboard is added to first artboard.
how do I accsss _var2 values and alter its values.

You can modify your _onRiveInit function to correctly access and modify
values in both the parent and nested artboards:
 void _onRiveInit(Artboard artboard) {

  var parentController = StateMachineController.fromArtboard(
  artboard,
  'SM1',
   onStateChange: _onStateChange,
 );
 artboard.addController(parentController!);
_var1 = parentController.findInput<double>('var1'); 

 RuntimeNestedArtboard? nestedArtboard = artboard as 
  RuntimeNestedArtboard;

if (nestedArtboard != null && nestedArtboard.childArtboard != null) {
  var nestedController = StateMachineController.fromArtboard(
    nestedArtboard.childArtboard!,
    'SM1', 
    onStateChange: _onStateChange,
  );
  nestedArtboard.childArtboard!.addController(nestedController!);
   _var2 = nestedController.findInput<double>('var2');  
  }

setState(() {
  _stateMachineController = parentController; 
 });
}


I'm getting the error : The getter 'childArtboard' isn't defined for the type 'RuntimeNestedArtboard'. please can you suggest me what did I miss.

Identify the Nested Artboard: Depending on how your Rive file is structured, there may be a specific way to access the nested artboard. If your nested artboard is part of an animation or directly instantiated, you might need to search through the artboard's objects to find it.

Properly Access the Nested Artboard: Since childArtboard isn't available, we need another method to access the nested artboard. One common approach is iterating through components or looking for a specific name if your artboards are named.
